# How to ignore this file pattern?

Tags: git

I want to ignore all files matching this pattern.

```
home - copy [1].php
home - copy [2].php
home - copy [3].php
filename - copy [1].php
anotherfile - copy [1].php
other - copy [1].php
```

There can be numbers inside [ and ]. What rule should be added in .gitignore for such files?

Comment: Since you are using `git` anyway, why do you have multiple copies of each file?

Comment: we just deployed git on our old projects. There are lots of such copies everywhere...

Comment: Which pattern? That's a list of files, not a pattern... Granted, there are several different possibilities within that file list for a pattern, but you should specify exactly which pattern. Is it `- copy [<number>].php` or simply `*.php` or ...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Apparently you can specify a number:

```
* - copy\ \[[0-9]*\].php
```

---

Unfortunately you can't use regex to specify a number in the [ ] but

```
* - copy\ \[*\].php
```

should work (although it would also filter `test - copy [ab].php` etc)